# Am getting String too long error using a loop

Tags: pine-script

I am using a counter to add the previous string to a new string.
Am quite sure that the resultant string value is less than 4096. But keep getting the String too long error!
What's the mistake I am making and what's the solution?

Thanks

```
indicator("My script")
test = array.new_float(0,0)
for i = 1 to 12
    array.push(test,time)


array.sort(test,order.descending)

var string fdate1label =""
for i = 0 to array.size(test)-1
    fdate1label:=fdate1label+"\n"+str.format("{0,date, dd-MM-y}",(array.get(test,i)))

if barstate.islast
    checklabel=label.new(bar_index+5, close, "dates " + fdate1label, style = label.style_label_lower_left, size = size.normal)
```

Comment: Well, it has more than 4096 chars, that's for sure. Do you really need that `var` keyword? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Removing the ```var``` variable did the trick.

I am trying to store 12 time variables(which will be bartimes eventually) and then print then as a label in the Date format.
The label should print all the stored dates in this format in separate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `var` keyword.

Your script is executed on every bar. When you have a `var`, its value is kept for the next execution.